# How to change attribute of object in C++ from static method

Tags: c++, static-methods

How to change object attribute from static method in C++? My method must be static.

Code:

```
class Wrapper
{
    private:
        double attribute; //attribute which I want to change
    public:
        Wrapper();
        ~Wrapper();
        static void method(double x);
}
```

I tried:

```
std::string Wrapper::method(double x)
{
    attribute = x;
}
```

But:

```
error: invalid use of member ‘Wrapper::attribute’ in static member function
```

Comment: Let's say you have 10 Wrapper object, how would this static method know which one should be modified? :)
If you really want this, pass a Wrapper object reference to the method function.

Comment: It is a kind of object which is and will be created only once.

Comment: How should the compiler know this?

Comment: Then why not simply make `attribute` static too? Or maybe turn the class into a singleton?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried to make attribute static, but I got error: undefined reference to `Wrapper::attribute.

Comment: Singleton is an antipattern, i wouldn't recommend it in any case. Without knowing what you want to achieve it's hard to advice a solution.

Comment: @wair92 And for that problem there are hundreds of questions and answers here on SO, not to talk about the thousands on the bigger Internet.

Comment: @wair92: You should define somewhere your static variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static member function cannot access a non-static member because there is no object whose member you'd be referring to. Sure, you could pass a reference to an object as a parameter as suggested, but that's just silly because you might just as well make the function a non-static member.

> It is a kind of object which is and will be created only once.

The simplest solution is to make the member `static`. `static` members can be accessed without an object because `static` members are shared for all instances.

> tried to make attribute static, but I got error: undefined reference to `Wrapper::attribute

That means you forgot to define the variable.

Comment: But you have to consider, that all instances of this type will share the same attribute. So if you change the attribute for "one" instance, it is changed everywhere else, too.

Comment: @KiraSama Like this: `double Wrapper::attribute;`

Comment: @user2079303 yes, sorry for question deletion, I got it fast before you comment, It's the same as defining a static function, thanks btw.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this way:

```
std::string Wrapper::method(double x, Wrapper& obj)
{
    obj.attribute = x;
}
```

But if you have such a problem, you should rethink your design. Methods referring to instance of a class have no reson to be static.

Static methods are not associated with any instance of the class but with the class itself. Compiler has no idea, that there is only one instance of this class. There are many possible solutions for your problem, but the correct one depends on what you want to achieve in a bigger scale.

Answer (score 1):

`method` is a class method and `attribute` is an instance variable. There is no instance and therefore no `attribute` when `method` is called in your current design. The only way to change an instance variable (like `attribute`) is to provide an instance of `Wrapper` to `method`. There are several possible solutions. Some ideas:

- an instance as a parameter to `method` (see Estiny's answer)
- a global instance of `Wrapper` (not advised)
- make `Wrapper` a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (in general not advised, but singletons can be a solutions in some situations)