# Static method changing private attributs

Tags: c++, oop

Is it clear in OOP(encapsulation) changing private attributes of object in static method?

Example.h

```
Class Example {
private:
     static int a1;
public:
     static void doSomething();
```

Example.cpp

```
void Example::doSomething(){
     Example::a1=5
}
```

Comment: you want to change private attrs in static method? is that your question?

Comment: yes i want to change attrs in static method, clear = good practice or something like that, if it is good when i do it

Comment: That's perfectly fine as long as you document the side effects of calling `doSomething`.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478983/how-to-change-attribute-of-object-in-c-from-static-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, using static private attributes is useful when you want every objects of the class (and the objects of the inherited classes) to share the same attribute. In this case, there is one and only version of the attribute. Thus, implementing a static method is giving you the possibility of accessing this attribute without using a specific object, like a global function would do, but global functions do not have access to private attributes of classes like static methods.

Those types of attributes and methods are called *Class attributes* and *Class methods*, due to their characteristic of sharing their content.

In your example, putting `doSomething()` has `static` will give you access to `a1` directly using `Example::doSomething()` somewhere else in the project, changing its value to `5`.

An example of using those concepts is with the use of a counter to keep track of the number of objects of a certain class. The counter would be incremented in the constructor and decremented in the destructor. A static method would be implemented accessing the value of the private static attribute with `ClassName::getPrivateStaticAttribute()`. Note that you can still call the `getPrivateStaticAttribute()` using an object (with -> or .), but the method will have no `this` pointer.